# Get return from .mjs script to Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, multiprocessing

I need to execute .mjs script about 200 times with another parameters (changableParametr):

```
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Metadata } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");

(async () => {
   let mintPubkey = new PublicKey(changableParametr);
   let tokenmetaPubkey = await Metadata.getPDA(mintPubkey);

   const tokenmeta = await Metadata.load(connection, tokenmetaPubkey);
   console.log(tokenmeta);
   })();
```

How get result to Python? I thought to use multiprocessing. Maybe expand this .mjs script to make .json file, because i need only one string from result. What is the easiest method to do this?

Comment: Maybe you want to run it from command prompt and get the result via os.system?

Comment: also fairly straightforward using `subprocess.run`, and capture the output of any print statements.